# Query string (with space in between) in php html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do a query string in html.
String that I want to pass is "Book Cover".
But I only managed to get Book.
How should I go about doing it?

Below is my code:

```
    <a href=book.php?category=Book Cover>Book Cover</a>
```

Comment: try quoting it = `href="book.php?category=Book Cover"`

Comment: ^---- bingo, nails it

Comment: Not a good solution... defiantly encode it correclty... whitespace would be %20

Comment: This is what I get after quoting it Book%20Cover

Comment: which is correct, check nareks response for more information about url encoding / decoding.

Answer (score 6):

You need to encode all your query string vars, For example with [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) / [rawurldecode](http://php.net/rawurldecode)

```
<a href="book.php?category=<?=rawurlencode('Book Cover')?>">Book Cover</a>
```

And in PHP:

```
$category = rawurldecode($_POST['category']);
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML the value stops at the space:

```
<a href=book.php?category=Book Cover>Book Cover</a>
                              ^
```

If you want to include a space inside a value in HTML you need to add quotes:

```
<a href="book.php?category=Book Cover">Book Cover</a> 
        ^                            ^
```

In HTML both single and double quotes are allowed.

Now the value itself has a problem, too:

```
book.php?category=Book Cover
                      `- URL stops here.
```

This is a *relative HTTP URL* and as for any HTTP URL the space character is a special value. It can normally not be part of the URL, therefore you need to encode it. This can be done as with any other special character in a HTTP URL with *triplet encoding* / *percentage-encoding* replacing the binary value of the character(s) with their hexadecimal number:

```
book.php?category=Book%20Cover
```

For the space you have, historically it is even a special-case, you can also encode it with the plus sign.

The later problem is often dealt with by the user agents, but the quotes in HTML are needed otherwise the value gets cut.

And it is generally good practice to place attribute values in HTML inside (double) quotes. So I suggest you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert to UTF-8 before encoding?

```
urlencode(utf8_encode($string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing double quotes

```
<a href="book.php?category=Book Cover">Book Cover</a>
```

Comment: There should never be white space on the url... encoding should always be applied.

Comment: tell that to the "awesome" website for my former city's tax dept, http://www.cityofbrookpark.com/tax%20dept/tax-forms.htm

Comment: @Uberfuzzy remembered me times when I create sites with Microsoft word and save as .html :)